# At what point is True randomness lost? True random number as a java.util.Random seed?

Tags: java, scala, random

Let's assume I have a reliably truly random source of random numbers, but it is very slow. It only give me a few hundreds of numbers every couple of hours.

Since I need way more than that I was thinking to use those few precious TRN I can get as seeds for java.util.Random (or scala.util.Random). I also always will pick a new one to generate the next random number.

So I guess my questions are: 
Can the numbers I generate from those Random instance in Java be considered truly random since the seed is truly random?
Is there still a condition that is not met for true randomness? 
If I keep on adding levels at what point will randomness be lost? 
Or (as I thought when I came up with it) is truly random as long as the stream of seeds is?

I am assuming that nobody has intercepted the stream of seeds, but I do not plan to use those numbers for security purposes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: *"reliably truly random?"* To my knowledge, true randomness is impossible to derive through programming.

Comment: I am not deriving it. I am getting my randoms from a TRNG ... only it is slow! Then I want to use those TRN to generate other TRN

Comment: FTR, it's still pseudo-random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pseudo random generator like `java.util.Random`, the next generated number in the sequence becomes predictable given only a few numbers from the sequence, so you will loose your "true randomness" very fast. Better use one of the generators provided by `java.security.SecureRandom` - these are all strong random generators with an VERY long sequence length, which should be pretty hard to be predicted.

Answer (score 1):

When you take out more bits, than you have put in they are for sure no longer truly random. The break point may even occur earlier if the random number generator is bad. This can be seen by considering the entropy of the sequences. The seed value determines the sequence completely, so there are at most as many sequences as seed values. If they are all distinct, the entropy is the same as that of the seeds (which is essentially the number of seed bits, assuming the seed is truly random).

However, if different seeds lead to the same pseudo random sequence the entropy of the sequences will be lower than that of the seeds. If we cut off the sequences after n bits, the entropy may be even lower.

But why care if you don't use it for security purposes? Are you sure the pseudo random numbers are not good enough for your application?

Comment: My question is more curiosity than actual application. I just want to understand at which point  this would not work anymore. Could you elaborate on the first part of your answer?

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: So are there any seeds' "collisions" in j.u.Random or j.s.SecureRandom? Or is there any stats about collisions (different seeds that give the same sequence) using those implementations?

Comment: I don't know, this would require a detailed study of the used algorithm.

Comment: Interesting lead there... thanks a lot I will try to do some research about that.

Answer (score 1):

Our java Random gives uniformly spread random numbers. That is not true randomness, which may yield five times the same number.

Furthermore for every specific seed the same sequence is generated (intentionally). With 2^64 seeds in general irrelevant. *(Note hackers could store the first ten numbers of every sequence; thereby rapidly catching up.)*

So if you at large intervals use a truely random number *as seed*, you will get a uniform distribution during that interval. In effect not very different from not using the true randomizers.

Now combining random sequences might reduce the randomness. Maybe translating the true random number to bytes, and xor-ing every new random number with another byte, might give a wilder variance.

*Please do not take my word only - I cannot guarantee the mathematical correctness of the above. A math/algorithmic forum might give more info.*

Comment: But here is the thing. I am getting as many j.u.Random instances as I can get seeds. And each time I need to generate a new number I pick a new instance. Wouldn't that system give true randomness?

Comment: Uniform distribution does not mean that you cannot have the same number five times in a row.

Comment: @le_douard yes, than has a fine randomness.